# URL rewriting - rewriting ID as some text

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

If I have this URL as follows:-

www.mysite.com/products/Product.aspx?id=101

and I want it to be re written as

www.mysite.com/products/ProductName1

How do I go about this?

I have been trying IIRF ISAPI Rewriter since long but no luck. IIRF Status report displays a warning that says blahblha.ini file could not be opened.

Is there some easy way to achieve what I want?

Please help.Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using URL Rewrite Module? 
http://forums.iis.net/t/1159315.aspx

Comment: in UrlRewrite you can specify your own rules how to rewrite the url. I don't fully know what do you mean by dynamic ID's.. The easiest way is to rewrite it so that the "?ID=XX" is always changed to "/XX" and the other way round - depending on from which perspective are you looking..

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the [MVC Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) to accomplish this?  More info on MVC routing from Scott Gu [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx).

Although not necessary, MVC will still support this format:

```
www.mysite.com/products/Product.aspx?id=101
```